# change column for .rowGrouoing in Datatables during runtime

Tags: jquery, datatables

```
myTable.dataTable().rowGrouping({
    iGroupingColumnIndex: id,
    sGroupBy: "name",
    bHideGroupingColumn: false,
    bExpandableGrouping: true,
    asExpandedGroups: []
});
```

I would like to switch the column used for grouping (variable id), How to do that? I can select the grouping id during runtime, run this and it shows the groups.

Than I do the same with another id, it also works, but throws error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined  into console.

After that, I can't change the id anymore.

What would be the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

OK, this helps (DataTables 1.10.x) - run this before changing the column.
It removes the grouping, before setting a new one

```
var oSettings = alarmTable.dataTableSettings[0];
for (f = 0; f < oSettings.aoDrawCallback.length; f++) {
    if (oSettings.aoDrawCallback[f].sName == 'fnRowGrouping') {
        oSettings.aoDrawCallback.splice(f, 1);
        break;
    }
}
oSettings.aaSortingFixed = null;
```

- just updated answer from [datatables remove rowgrouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967944/datatables-remove-rowgrouping) to fit 1.10.x